# Database design question around nested columns vs separate tables

Tags: powerbi, api

I am working with an API endpoint in Power Query where the data is a bunch of nested tables. When I expand all of those columns I am getting duplicate data (the total count of the rows is nearly 8 times as much as it should be).

In theory, I could just visualise only the unique count in Power BI, but I was wondering if it's better to separate the queries into separate tables (one for each nested table) and then create a relationship with those tables?

One thing to note is that there's an API concurrency limit that prevents me from pulling more than two at the same time, so could that be an issue? In other words, will it see each table as a separate pull?

Sorry, I know this may be a basic question, but I've not been able to find any guidance in the documentation I am working with.

Comment: What database system does the data live in? What do you mean by nested tables? (An example would probably be helpful.)